# Angular Observable Component and Service Interaction

Tags: angular, service, components, observable

What would the update TODO function call look like with Corey Rylan’s code example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fh1kyp
?

Specifically, if I have a `todo: Observable<Todo>` in the Angular Component, how do I call `update( todo: Todo )` of the Angular Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure about what you are looking for but have you tried subscribing to the `todo` variable of type observable and then calling the `update` function from inside the subscribe function?

```
todo.subscribe(todoValue => this.service.update(todoValue));
```

What this will do is subscribe to the todo Observable and whenever something is received, it will call the update function.